# Is there a more efficient or improved approach to creating a web app Java syntax checker that differs from the logic used in a typing game?

Tags: javascript, html, css, logic

Problem involves creating a web app that functions as a real-time syntax checker for Java code. The app should allow users to write Java code in a text area while comparing it to a predefined Java code snippet, highlighting incorrect parts, and awarding points for correctly typed code elements.

I've created a basic prototype for a web app that checks the syntax of Java code in real-time. Originally, I adapted a tutorial in Youtube for a typing game to serve as the foundation, but I've modified it to function as a syntax checker(sorry for the poor code quality). The app currently awards points for each correctly typed Java keyword. However, I'm encountering issues with the logic, as it's not robust and can be easily broken. I'd greatly appreciate any assistance in improving the app's functionality. Thank you

Disclaimer: I'm just a student so be kind please.

The code for index.html

```js
const codeDisplay = document.getElementById("codeDisplay");
const codeInput = document.getElementById("codeInput");
let score = 0;

// Replace the following with a valid code snippet for syntax checking
const codeSnippet = `import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your age");
        int age = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println(age);
    }
}`;

// Extract and store keywords
const keywords = new Set(extractKeywordsFromCode(codeSnippet));

// Function to extract keywords from code snippet
function extractKeywordsFromCode(codeSnippet) {
    const keywordPattern = /\b\w+\b/g;
    const keywordMatches = [...codeSnippet.matchAll(keywordPattern)];
    const keywords = keywordMatches.map(match => match[0]);
    return [...new Set(keywords)];
}

codeDisplay.innerHTML = '';

// Create an array of character elements for display
const displayChars = Array.from(codeSnippet).map(char => {
    const charElement = document.createElement('span');
    charElement.innerHTML = char;
    return charElement;
});

displayChars.forEach(charElement => {
    codeDisplay.appendChild(charElement);
});

codeInput.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if (e.key === 'Tab') {
        e.preventDefault();
        const caretPos = codeInput.selectionStart;
        const spaces = '    ';
        const currentText = codeInput.value;
        const newText = currentText.substring(0, caretPos) + spaces + currentText.substring(caretPos);
        codeInput.value = newText;
        codeInput.selectionStart = caretPos + spaces.length;
        codeInput.selectionEnd = caretPos + spaces.length;
    }
});

let totalCorrectChars = 0;

codeInput.addEventListener('input', () => {
    const inputText = codeInput.value;
    const inputChars = Array.from(inputText);
    const inputWords = inputText.split(/\s+|\(|\)|\./).filter(word => word.trim() !== '');

    inputWords.forEach(inputWord => {
        if (keywords.has(inputWord)) {
            score++;
            document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
            keywords.delete(inputWord);
            console.log(score);
            console.log(inputWords);
        }
    });
    

    displayChars.forEach((charElement, index) => {
        if (index >= inputChars.length) {
            // This character has not been typed yet, so don't mark it
            charElement.classList.remove('incorrect');
            charElement.classList.remove('correct');
        } else if (inputChars[index] === codeSnippet[index]) {
            charElement.classList.remove('incorrect');
            charElement.classList.add('correct');
        } else {
            charElement.classList.remove('correct');
            charElement.classList.add('incorrect');
        }
    });

});
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #1e0555;
}

body,
.quote-input {
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS",
        sans-serif;
}

.container {
    background-color: #f0db4f;
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    width: 700px;
    max-width: 90%;
}

.score {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0rem;
    font-size: 3rem;
    color: #f0db4f;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#codeDisplay {
    white-space: pre;
}

.quote-display {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    margin-left: calc(1rem + 2px);
    margin-right: calc(1rem + 2px);
}

.quote-input {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #a1922e;
    outline: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 8rem;
    margin: auto;
    resize: none;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.quote-input:focus {
    border-color: black;
}

.correct {
    color: green;
}

.incorrect {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <title>Speed Typing</title>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="score" id="score">0</div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="quote-display" id="codeDisplay"></div>
            <textarea class="quote-input" id="codeInput"></textarea>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Initially, I had a basic typing game code that I wanted to adapt into a syntax checker.

I tried various approaches, including checking for correctness character by character and line by line, using keywords to validate input, and incrementing a score when correct keywords were typed.

I encountered issues with my code not correctly recognizing keywords, handling indentation, and giving points based on correctness.

I expected the app to check the syntax of Java code in real-time, validate keywords, and increment a score when the user typed the correct keywords.

I was seeking help to improve the logic of my web app and make it more robust and accurate in checking syntax while also awarding points accurately.

TL;DR: The current web app prototype for Java syntax checking faces several challenges. It employs a limited line-by-line and character-by-character syntax checking approach, leading to incomplete analysis. The scoring mechanism relies on individual keywords but lacks context. Most importantly, the code doesn't grasp essential Java syntax rules, such as correct placement of braces and semicolons.

Question: what can i do to create a robust real time scoring system for correct syntax in java and not just a typing game but for syntax?

Comment: In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: I know this might sound like a stupid question, but what's the point of copying code verbatim? It certainly won't teach anyone to code...